# No puedo acceder a los estaticos de mi contenedor docker

Tags: php, codeigniter, docker, nginx, docker-compose

Tengo un proyecto con codeigniter en un contenedor de docker, al ejecutarlo funciona correctamente y sale por el puero 80, hice un cambio en el docker compose ya que voy a utilizar varios contenedores en el mismo servidor

```
ports:
  - 8000:80
```

Ahora he usado nginx como proxy inverso para servir cada uno de mis contenedores

```
server {
      server_name midominio.com;
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;

      location /miapp1/ {
              proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      location /miapp2/ {
              proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
}
```

El problema es que los estaticos no cargan, cuando ingreso por el navegador a

```
http://midominio.com/miapp1/
```

Los estaticos apuntan a la raiz del dominio

```
http://midominio.com/assets/plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

Modifique en mi archivo config.php de codeigniter

```
$config['base_url'] = $root.'miapp1/';
```

Y la ruta cambia a la que necesito, pero ahora no encuentra el archivo en esa ruta

```
http://midominio.com/miapp1/assets/plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que de que manera puedo solucionar este problema, agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.